# Looking to build a web based chat. Any suggestions?

Tags: xml, ajax, xmpp, chat

I was looking to build a web based chat application. My primary idea was in the direction of using AJAX and transferring XML messages to-and-fro a centralized server (used for synchronization)

However, i recently came across XMPP and would like to know how feasible it is to use it as a web based chat client and server, and how easy it is to implement it in PHP.

I would really like some inputs from the gurus here about any other technical approaches that i can take. The chat has to be completely web based, but might be ported to an iPhone application sometime later in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this [browser based chat](http://github.com/abhinavsingh/JAXL/tree/master/app/boshchat/) examples of [Jaxl library](http://jaxl.net) . JAXL (Jabber XMPP Library) is written in PHP and you can extend the packaged sample examples for your use case.

Checkout [this blog post](http://abhinavsingh.com/blog/2010/08/php-code-setup-and-demo-of-jaxl-boshchat-application/) on how to setup the sample browser chat application on your local system.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to build something simple and fast, use memcache as a queue.
When user A sends a message, put it in a queue for user B who periodically polls using AJAX.

You could also experiment with node.js which is great for chat applications.

I've implemented XMPP as well and I found it to be too much work to have it work properly and stable.

Comment: can i have an XMPP server running on my server ? does XMPP come as a software to setup on server ?